# Why do threads not increase runtime past a certain point

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

Basically, I have a table with the number of threads in a program and the runtime of the program (in seconds)

```
Threads Runtime
1       12.06
2       6.03
3       4.02
4       4.556
5       4.154
10      3.216
15      2.68
20      3.082
25      2.814
50      3.35
```

I understand why having threads/concurrency drastically increases the runtime to start with, however, I am slightly confused about when we get between 10-50 threads the runtime stays relatively stable and does not seem to be increasing at all, despite the number of threads increasing by a large amount.

Why is this?

Comment: How many cores does the CPU have?

Comment: What to you mean with “Runtime”? The execution time? If so, then say it. Further, stop saying “increasing” when the posted values are decreasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads represent *subdivisions of* their parent Process.

In your situation, I predict that most of your threads simply have nothing to do!

The "one-thread" case predicts your worst-case runtime.  As expected, "two threads" divides it in half, and "three threads" into thirds.  "Four threads and beyond" make it clear that there is no additional benefit.  The rest of them have nothing to do.